# Automatically mark ASP.Net controls which have a RequiredFieldValidator on them

Tags: asp.net, css, automation, requiredfieldvalidator

Is there a clean and centralized way to automatically designate a background color or other CSS property for ASP.Net controls (i.e. a TextBox) with an enabled RequiredFieldValidator?

Currently I have manually set the background color of required controls to yellow. I would like to replace that with a central method so if the client requests a different color or marker or if a field's status changes from required to not or vice versa, I won't miss any of the controls.

Thanks

**Update**

This site is pre-compiled. Can something append a Css Class or other standards-compliant flag to items in the ControlToValidtate property at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

Why not add a css class of required. You can have multiple classes on a single control by space delimiting them so imagine an input field which takes a number:

Now I can have two classes one which right aligns the text and one which handles the required field requirements.

## Edit

One option before the page is rendered to walk through each control in the page, and if it's a required field validator, then find it's corresponding control and set the css property; however, this is a lot of work for somethign which you can tackle at design time.

Comment: Because unfortunately the validators don't render any trace by which to identify those elements.

Comment: Yes but you know at design time that you added a required field validator.

Comment: Exactly. I've even taken this to the next level in one of my projects and dynamically append validation controls based on the classes in the  CssClass attribute (e.g. if the CssClass="required email", I'll append a required field validator and regex validator dynamically)

Comment: Ohh now that is interesting the inverse of my edit...neat idea

Comment: @Chris - so you are going the other way around then? Adding <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... /> to items that have class="required" in them?

Comment: Sounds like he is but after thinking about this, if you want different validation messages for example then this doesn't make sense.